# How to combine the common substring from 2 strings in PHP

Tags: php, duplicates, substring, string-comparison

I have 2 strings

```
$old_string = "a,b,c,d,";
```

The $new_string with get from a form via post method.

```
$new_string = "c,d,e,f,";
```

What is the best way to get the common substring from 2 string above?

```
   $common_string ="a,b,c,d,e,f,";
```

And how to show that having c and d were removed from $new_string?

Thank you very much

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` function to convert these into arrays then take the union

```
$old_string = "a,b,c,d,";
$oldArray =  explode($old_string, ',');
$new_string = "c,d,e,f,";
$newArray = explode($new_string, ',');

$result =  array_unique(array_merge($oldArray, $newArray));

print_r($result); //it is unique and merged
```

Hope this helps